# Problems instaling numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to install numpy in the command line with

```
pip install numpy
```

and with the comand

```
pip3 install numpy
```

and both output the same long error message spanning a lot of lines and I cannot seem to find the solution anywhere else. Also yes I ran the pip show numpy and it outputted that the module was not found

I cannot show the whole error message or stack overflow will not allow it to be sent but here are some bits of it.

```
DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpt96cv69x'
     cwd: C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy
```

Several updates:
Firstly I am using python version  3.9.0.

Secondly I cannot add the whole error message as stack overflow will not allow the question to be published, however I can show bits of the error message I feel sound important for this problem.

Thirdly if there is no way to correct this problem could anyone tell me if its possible to manually install python modules without using cmd prompt.

Lastly it seems only numpy is being affected by this as I am still able to install other python modules with no problems. For some reason at the wheel metadata part, it gives the error.

Here is some more pieces of the error message.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\logan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\logan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwyokpy44' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please, add a bit more of the error response...

Comment: Please provide more information, the entire error message. Also, it is evident that you're using Python 3.9, but it woulf be worth mentioning that explicitly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the python3.9 problem, NumPy don't have binary wheel ready yet for Python 3.9 version

view *Sept 14,2020* note in numpy website [here](https://numpy.org/news/)

> Sept 14, 2020 – Python 3.9 will be released in a few weeks. If you are an early adopter of Python versions, you may be disappointed to find that NumPy (and other binary packages like SciPy) will not have binary wheels ready on the day of the release. It is a major effort to adapt the build infrastructure to a new Python version and it typically takes a few weeks for the packages to appear on PyPI and conda-forge. In preparation for this event, please make sure to

recommend downgrade to 3.8 first before this problem was solved

Comment: what is your python version

Comment: mine is on version python 3.9.0

Comment: i think i found the problem

Comment: how do i downgrade my python version